# unique_ptr deleter is causing a crash in my program

Tags: c++, memory, destructor, unique-ptr

At run time when I close my program I get the error: "crt detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer." I followed the program execution through a destructor to the deleter of the unique ptr and the error occured on the call to the deleter function. Another problem I want to mention is that for some reason the class defenition that the unique ptr is in requires that it has a public copy constructor. I tried to replicate these problems in another project with a different class and the same one, removing the copy constructor and destructor and changing the access labes. I couldn't replicate the same problems - the biggest difference between these two projects is the one with problems is a shared library, could this be the problem? Having to define the copy constructor although annoying and redundant I dont really care to much about, any speculations or advice on this memory error would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Post code, asking a list of questions makes it harder to answer.  You can create multiple questions on the site though. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> crt detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Yes, this message *appears* when you call delete, but it's saying it *found* an error.  Not caused one.  Somewhere in your code, you are writing past the end of an array, and then during the delete, the memory manager found "footprints" in an out-of-bounds area.

Before each and every array access, put in :

```
assert(index<array_size);
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you have been quite helpful :)

Comment: Whoa, every time I post an answer like this the reply has always been "That's too much work!"  An alternative is to use `std::vector` instead of naked arrays, and it should catch boundary errors for you.